# Print input arrays by rows in correct order with PHP

Tags: php, arrays, forms, for-loop, foreach

I have the following sets of data inside the form that are dynamically added by JavaScript so the user can add unlimited number of data rows:

```
<div class="row">
    <input type="text" value="" name="title[]" />

    <input type="text" value="" name="label[]" />
    <input type="text" value="" name="value[]" />

    <input type="text" value="" name="label[]" />
    <input type="text" value="" name="value[]" />

    <input type="text" value="" name="label[]" />
    <input type="text" value="" name="value[]" />
</div>

<div class="row">
    <input type="text" value="" name="title[]" />

    <input type="text" value="" name="label[]" />
    <input type="text" value="" name="value[]" />

    <input type="text" value="" name="label[]" />
    <input type="text" value="" name="value[]" />
</div>

<div class="row">
    <input type="text" value="" name="title[]" />
    <input type="text" value="" name="label[]" />
    <input type="text" value="" name="value[]" />
</div>
```

My objective is then be able to print/post it in the same order so it would look like:

```
<h2>Title</h2>
<div class="label">Label</div>
<div class="value">Value</div>

<h2>Title</h2>
<div class="label">Label</div>
<div class="value">Value</div>

<h2>Title</h2>
<div class="label">Label</div>
<div class="value">Value</div>
```

My problem is that I can not figure out how to loop through sets of data and print one by one in the same order. Here is my current code but it just does not make sense what it prints and I know I am doing this the wrong way.

```
foreach ($_POST['title'] as $title) {
    echo $title;    

    foreach ($_POST['label'] as $label) {
        echo $label;    
    }
}
```

I would appreciate any help.
Thank you.

**EDIT: Just wanted to note that rows may have different number of inputs.**

Comment: you should not use foreach for `$label` just get the key of `$title` and use it to get the label of that title

Comment: Make the names into a two dimensional array. i.e. `name="title[0[]"` `name="label[0][]"` `name="value[0][]"` etc. 
[Your form with names in this format](http://pastebin.com/CS4zCqJP). 
Having the post array with [grouping of names within groupId](http://pastebin.com/rmE21CAq) may make the coding
slighty easier?

Comment: The variable size of input rows makes it interesting. 
I have mentioned about identifying 'groups'. 
Alas, when i tried to write code to process them it was 'awkward'. 
I eventually realized that a `mapping` between `POST` and 'variable sized groups' is required. 
I mapped the worse case mentioned previously.  
Maybe useful: [31797167/class-map-POST-array-to-required-group-structure](http://pastebin.com/XvYVp0BS). 
Example of use [31797167/DEMO-of-mapping-class](http://pastebin.com/XZAdekBy).

Answer (score 1):

If the labels and values always come in same-sized groups with each title, you can use a `for` loop nested in your `foreach` loop.

```
$group_size = 3;

foreach ($_POST['title'] as $i => $title) {
    echo $title;
    for ($j = $i*$group_size; $j < ($i+1)*$group_size; $j++) {
        echo $_POST['label'][$j];
        echo $_POST['value'][$j];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but what if it has a different number of inputs per set? Please see my edited question above. I think in this case that wont work as it the count is wrong.

Comment: How are they related? Are there always 3 label/value for each title?

Comment: the user has two buttons: [Add title] [Add Row], by adding row it always append label & value inputs. This way it can add unlimited number of rows. Also it can add title before or after any row. This is why I just want to print, post in the exact same order as it is generated by user.

Comment: Then you need to redesign the form so that the label and value fields have a group number in their names. Otherwise there's no way to know how they should be grouped with the title. See @RyanVincent's comment above.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
<form method="post">

<div class="row">
    title 1:
    <input type="text" value="" name="title[]" />
    label 1:
    <input type="text" value="" name="label[]" />
    value 1:
    <input type="text" value="" name="value[]" />
</div>

<div class="row">
    title 2:
    <input type="text" value="" name="title[]" />
    label 2:
    <input type="text" value="" name="label[]" />
    value 2:
    <input type="text" value="" name="value[]" />
</div>

<div class="row">
    title 3:
    <input type="text" value="" name="title[]" />
    label 3:
    <input type="text" value="" name="label[]" />
    value 3:
    <input type="text" value="" name="value[]" />
</div>

<input type="submit">
</form>

<?php


foreach ($_POST['title'] as $i => $title) {
  echo"
  <ul>
      <li>{$_POST['title'][$i]}</li>
      <li>{$_POST['label'][$i]}</li>
      <li>{$_POST['value'][$i]}</li>
  </ul>
  ";
}
```

See demo [here](http://www.angelcool.net/stackoverflow/31797167.php). Good luck!

Comment: Thank you, but what if it has different number of inputs per set? Please see my edited question above. I think in this case that wont work as it the count is wrong.